# How to fix an incorrect include path

Tags: module, magento-1, event-observer, model

I am creating a custom Module and Event Observer.
I am using this tutorial as a base [-tutorial](http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/).

My directory structure is just like in the tutorial

```
-app/
--code/
---local/
----[NameSpace]/
-----[Module]/
------Helper/
------Model/
------etc/
------sql/
```

In the Model folder I have a file named Observer.php

It contains:

```
class [NameSpace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function receiveEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $result = Mage::getModel('[Namespace]_[Module]/example')
                    ->exampleFunction($order);
   return true;
}
```

I know that I have my observer and module set up correctly because if I put test code (write to a log) in the observer it runs fine.

I'm having trouble getting 'exampleFunction' to run. I get an error that says that it cannot include the correct file

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/[NameSpace]/[Module]/Model/Example.php' for inclusion
```

This is occuring in `Varien/Autoload.php`. The paths look fine **except** that it is sticking `Mage` on the front of the path. If it just said `[NameSpace]/[Module]/Model/Example.php` then it would work perfectly.

I do have a file named `Example.php` in the `Model` folder.

Does anyone know why it is putting 'Mage' on the front of the path and how I can remove it? I don't want to hack the actual autoload file, but I don't understand what's different about my code that it's not including this file correctly.

---

edit:
Here is my config.xml file within the Module. I substituted the actual namespace and module names with the words NameSpace and Module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <NameSpace_Module>
           <version>0.0.1</version>
    </NameSpace_Module>
</modules>

<global>

    <blocks> <!--Block folder--> 
        <Module> 
            <class>NameSpace_Module_Block</class> 
        </Module> 
    </blocks> 

    <blocks>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <account_navigation>NameSpace_Module_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </blocks>

    <models>
        <Module>
            <class>NameSpace_Module_Model</class>
             <resourceModel>Module_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </Module>
        <Module_mysql4>
            <class>NameSpace_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <missedorders>
                    <table>NameSpace_missedorders</table>
                </missedorders>
            </entities>
        </Module_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
         <missedorders_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </missedorders_setup>
        <missedorders_write>
            <connection><use>core_write</use></connection>
        </missedorders_write>
        <missedorders_read>
            <connection><use>core_read</use></connection>
        </missedorders_read>
    </resources>
    <events>
        <customer_address_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Module>
                <class>Module/observer</class>
                <method>receiveEvent</method>
                </Module>
            </observers>
        </customer_address_save_after>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <Module>
                    <class>Module/observer</class>
                    <method>afterOrder</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </Module >
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
        <controller_front_send_response_after>
            <observers>
                <Module>
                    <class>Module/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeFrontInit</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </Module >
            </observers>
        </controller_front_send_response_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <Module>
            <class>NameSpace_Module_Helper</class>
        </Module>
    </helpers>
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <Module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
                <frontName>Module</frontName>
            </args>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
                <frontName>first-time-reset-process</frontName>
            </args>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
                <frontName>user-approval</frontName>
            </args>
        </Module>

    </routers>


    <layout>
        <updates>
            <Module module="NameSpace_Module">
                <file>namespace_Module.xml</file>
            </Module>
        </updates>
    </layout>  
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
                <frontName>Module</frontName>
            </args>
        </Module>
    </routers>
</admin>

<default>
    <web>
        <routers>
            <Module>
                <area>frontend</area>
                <class>NameSpace_Module_Controller_Router</class>
            </Module>
        </routers>
    </web>
</default>
```

Comment: can you post the content of the `config.xml` file of your module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace

```
Mage::getModel('[Namespace]_[Module]/example')
```

with

```
Mage::getModel('[Module]/example')
```

The first part of the `getModel` parameter is the tag name you defined in `config.xml` right under the `<models>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Mage::getModel('namespace/model')` or `Mage::getSingleton('namespace/model')`, you have to define a node `global/models/namespace/class` with the content `[NameSpace]_[Module]_Model`.

If this class is missing, the classname resolving fallback on Mage:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1253
\Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName
if (empty($className)) {
    $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
}
```

Comment: Please explain to me why one downvote, so I can learn.

Comment: That solved my problem. I forgot to add the <global /> tag